# ¿ Como cargar una imagen ubuntu modificada a Docker?

Tags: linux, docker

Bueno estoy intentando cargar una imagen de ubuntu modificada llamada ubuntu2, para el cual comence por logearme desde linux que tengo alojado en una maquina virtual y comence con:

```
docker login
```

Ahi puse mi ID y contraseña de mi cuenta de Docker y me sale: error storing credentials

Quisiera saber a que se debe este error

Answer (score 2):

Te falta un paquete que te permita guardar eso.

`sudo apt install -y gnupg2 pass`

Luego lo intentas de nuevo. El proceso completo sería algo como

```
sudo apt install -y gnupg2 pass
docker logout
docker login
```

(Tomado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66895530/236345))